# JSZip extract file objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, extract, jszip

I am extracting a zip file with JSZip by doing the following:

```
jszip.loadAsync(zipFile)
['then'](function(zip) {
    return bluebird.map(Object.keys(zip.files), function (filename) {
        // converts the compressed file to a string of its contents
        return zip.files[filename].async('string').then(function (fileData) {
            // fileData is a string of the contents
        })
    })
})
```

However, the output of this extraction is an array of strings of the file contents. I was wondering if it was possible to get an array of file objects as the output instead because I need the file object later.

I have tried to do

```
new File(fileData.split('\n'), filename)
```

But it loses the original file formatting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `File` constructor [takes](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-constructor-params) a list of BufferSource (ArrayBuffer, Uint8Array, etc), Blob or string. If you split the content on `\n`, you will remove these `\n`. `File` will then concatenate each string without re-adding the new lines.

Use a blob instead:

```
return zip.files[filename].async('blob').then(function (fileData) {
    return new File([fileData], filename);
})
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed.
ps for future people who may use this. The line should be 
`return new File([fileData], filename)`

Comment: You're right, I messed up the variable name. I'll edit my answer to fix that.